# Send server max integer

Tags: java, sockets, server

Connects to a local server at port 3333, receives a line of integers from the Server, then finds the maximum number of integers and sends that value to the server. I'm placing all values from the line of integers into an arraylist, going through and finding the max; however, when I'm printing to the server, I get a BindException and my test fails.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        ArrayList<Integer> val = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        // contact the server
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 3333);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),
                true);

        while (scanner.hasNextInt()) { 
            int num = scanner.nextInt();
            val.add(num);  
        }
        int max = val.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < val.size(); i++) {
            if (val.get(i) > max) {
                max = val.get(i);
            }
        }
        writer.println(max);

        scanner.close();
        writer.close();
        socket.close();

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you mean: *BindException*

Comment: yes I did mean Bind Exception

Comment: What causes `while (scanner.hasNextInt())` to exit the loop? How does the scanner know that there are no more values to read? Could it be that it's because the server has **closed the connection**? So if the connection has been closed, why would you not expect an error trying to send something back?

Comment: ...when the scanner cannot locate any more numbers. It's a boolean expression, exits when there are no more numbers if I'm not mistaken